# alternative to viewpager for android swipe with tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment, fragmenttransaction

is there anyway to have swiping with tabs without using viewpager and also not doing a bunch of gesture detection? if not could someone post a sample of what's needed with the gesture detection. I'm hoping to get the left swipe gesture and then do a supportFragmentTransaction everytime. I would use viewpager but it's the buggiest thing since ant hills and doesn't work. basically I have 5 tabs with 5 fragments and just want to swipe between them and have tabs and hopefully have it circular so that when I'm on the last tab and swipe right it goes to the first. Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: "I would use viewpager but it's the buggiest thing since ant hills and doesn't work" -- it works for lots of other developers.

Comment: well for me it won't load list fragments past the 3rd position for no reason so I need an alternative.

Comment: "for no reason" -- I suspect that [there are reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252806/offscreen-viewpager-fragments-wont-render-after-1st-time-loaded). I doubt that you are going to find an easy solution to your problem, simply because most developers use `ViewPager` for horizontally-swiped page-at-a-time UIs, particularly those offering tabbed indicators.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you give a hint how to draw offscreen with the ViewPager without settings clipChildren to false?

Comment: @box: No, because I have never tried that. You might wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, perhaps with more details.